# How to delete mp3 file after the bot played it

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I am trying to create a music bot and now I want the bot to delete the current playing song after it finished playing. There's my code:

```py
import asyncio

import os
import discord
from discord.embeds import Embed
from discord.file import File
from discord.player import AudioPlayer
from youtube_dl.utils import smuggle_url, update_url_query
from youtube_search import YoutubeSearch
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import bot
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '/music_files/%(id)s.mp3',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' 
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source: discord.FFmpegPCMAudio, *, data: dict, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.thumbnail = data.get('thumbnail')
        self.url = data.get('webpage_url')
        self.uploader = data.get('uploader')
        self.uploader_url = data.get('uploader_url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)

class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        global player
        """Plays from a url (almost anything youtube_dl supports)"""
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

            await ctx.send("Started playing!")
    @play.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Music(client))
```

It's saving the files to a folder called "music_files" with the format videoid.mp3
I noticed that it's logging something in the cmd when `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` is added to the main.py file under the imports, is there maybe a way to use it?

Note: The code is a modified version of [basic_voice.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py) by Rapptz.

Edit: I found a way:

```py
            folder = './music_files'
            for song in os.listdir(folder):
                file_path = os.path.join(folder, song)
                try:
                    if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
                        os.unlink(file_path)
                    elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                        shutil.rmtree(file_path)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Failed to delete %s. Reason %s' % (file_path, e))
```

Comment: You're supposed to add a [**MINIMAL** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not your whole code

Comment: Changed it that it's runable in a cog. Removed all unnecessary parts.

Comment: You can name the file with the `guild.id` each time to get it. That way it will overwrite each time a new file is being played. so it will be `12345.mp3`.

Comment: @Abdulaziz this won't work because if the bot is playing something on guild 1 and on guild 2 someone wants to play something, it's going to play the same music from guild 1 not guild 2. And if you mean that the file is named for each guild, someday if the bot has gotten bigger there will be so many files.

Comment: @EckigerLuca The name would be specific for the guild using its ID. If you save a new file with the same name the old one should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the file with `os.remove(f'PATH/{videoid}.mp3')`

Comment: Thanks, that gave me an idea how to solve it